# Обработка EAGAIN после poll(); send()

Tags: linux, c, сеть, передача-данных

Есть tcp сокет. Требуется передать n байт данных с таймаутом на отправку. Было принято решение перевести сокет в не блокирующий режим

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

После делать poll() с требуемым таймаутом

```
pollfd somePollfd;
somePollfd.fd = socketFD;
somePollfd.events = POLLOUT;
poll(&somePollfd, 1, timeout);
```

По идеи, когда poll() устанавливает флаг POLLOUT в somePollfd.revents, можно выполнять send(). В мануале к poll написано (https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html):

```
POLLOUT
       Writing is now possible, though a write larger than the
       available space in a socket or pipe will still block
       (unless O_NONBLOCK is set).
```

Не могу понять что делать, если размер данных, которые пытаюсь отправить больше, чем "доступное место в сокете". Да, поскольку установлен не блокирующий режим, поток программы не будет заблокирован. Но что дальше? Если я опять вызову poll(), он сообщит, что я могу отправить данные. Но я не могу отправить такое количество данных.

Вариант отправить поток в сон для ожидания отпадает.
Вариант вычислять нужный размер данных для отправки отпадает.
В идеале как-то узнать, какое количество данных за раз можно отправить, не уходя в блокировку. Если такое возможно, то как? Можно решение исключительно под linux

Comment: Насколько помню, какой-то из `ioctl()`-ов позволяет узнать доступный в данный момент размер. Вообще, читайте man 7 socket (и SEE ALSO там). Кстати, если используете poll/select, то можно не делать сокет неблокируемым

Comment: Следует вычислять нужный размер данных для отправки.